# when we can say that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n)$?

Tags: analysis, limsup-and-liminf

when we can say that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n)$? (What conditions must have the function $f$?)

Comment: Is this supposed to hold for every $a_n$ or just one? In particular are you asking for conditions on the function *and* the sequence, or just the function.

Comment: for every $a_n\in\lbrace a_n\rbrace$ . Both of them ,please.

Comment: Well then, in particular it has to hold for convergent sequences, so that $f$ must be continuous for sure.

Comment: It also has to hold for sequences that just alternate between two values (like $2,7,2,7,2,7,\dots$). That forces $f$ to be non-decreasing.  And as far as I can see, the combination of continuous (from the comment by @AdamHughes) and non-decreasing is not only necessary but sufficient as well.

Comment: Thankyou so much. Can you introduce me a reference on this?

Comment: Anything that talks about continuity and monotonicity should be good, so just look for any intro to real analysis book.